# Getting exception in struts2 using jasper report

Tags: jsp, struts2, jasper-reports

I've created an application in struts2 and I use jasper for reporting. But i'm getting some exception in the browser as given below.

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this problem?

My code what I've done is below:

**report1.jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="null" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d4884678-fb84-4dba-a9f5-8d90964cd9b6">
    <style name="Title" forecolor="#FFFFFF" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Bold"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#CCCCCC" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="18" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="14" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Detail" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0EFEF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT
     login.`id` AS login_id,
     login.`name` AS login_name,
     login.`pass` AS login_pass
FROM
     `login` login]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="login_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="login_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="login_pass" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="102" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement uuid="dcbcd4a5-4dd4-4bd6-b29b-e5ad87b214c7" x="725" y="0" width="77" height="102"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["cherry.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="f92c03b7-8765-4013-9118-9daa8a9d5718" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="721" height="66" backcolor="#000000"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="f17f45bb-09e4-4c23-a40a-8c63b01a3866" style="Title" x="0" y="0" width="370" height="66"/>
                    <box topPadding="4" leftPadding="4" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="4"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <font isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Cherry Title]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="6f8f92fe-182e-42ff-ab37-154a07540218" style="SubTitle" x="370" y="37" width="316" height="29"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="22" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Cherry SubTitle]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="75ed2a4a-20d4-4a9b-9ec6-84228e21204d" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="70" width="721" height="32" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CC0000"/>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement uuid="5664ed89-b46d-4ff6-8d8a-c9bcfe819097" x="553" y="12" width="144" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="12"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="18" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="62448e30-8579-4e8d-a460-078762b80f02" style="Column header" x="0" y="0" width="265" height="18" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[login_id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="5b3d753c-0b30-4735-9fb6-65539c1b35cf" style="Column header" x="265" y="0" width="265" height="18" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[login_name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="220c90dc-095d-4e70-ba22-60cf2488e184" style="Column header" x="530" y="0" width="265" height="18" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[login_pass]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="18" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="8c04906d-c548-420f-a050-46507f5da0dc" style="Row" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="797" height="18"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="4e69e264-6905-4a70-a6e6-da0b5fd8b7ea" style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="265" height="18"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{login_id}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="e96a557f-770b-4eeb-b7b0-485c86952fb7" style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="265" y="0" width="265" height="18"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{login_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="246e8199-e7ae-43f6-935a-1695418b7ef0" style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="530" y="0" width="265" height="18"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{login_pass}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="7" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement uuid="3497c8b2-88b1-4d5e-898c-634159a172f5" positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="3" width="555" height="1"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="9d9f5a83-dbbd-46b4-b053-c8a0e8387705" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="25" forecolor="#D0B48E" backcolor="#000000"/>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement uuid="0360093b-11f7-46ff-92da-34c7459baa7c" style="Column header" x="757" y="3" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="e6b56da8-90e0-495d-bacc-d04606b3257a" style="Column header" x="677" y="3" width="80" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement uuid="611e2099-8b7e-455d-a8c8-37a4ae4b3e0e" style="Column header" x="2" y="3" width="197" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**JasperAction.java** (struts2 action class)

```
package action;

import com.lowagie.text.Anchor;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



import model.Person;
import model.Phone;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class JasperAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return SUCCESS;  
    }

public static ArrayList<Person> getBeanCollection() {
        ArrayList as=new ArrayList();
                as.add("val");
        return as;
    }

}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

 <package name="default" extends="jasperreports-default,struts-default">

    <action name="myJasperTest" class="action.JasperAction">

    <result name="success" type="jasper">
            <param name="location">/jasper/report1.jasper</param>
            <param name="dataSource">beanCollection</param>
            <param name="format">PDF</param>
        </result>

        <result name="error" type="jasper">/Error.jsp</result>

    </action>

</package>


</struts>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Struts2Jasper</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Header</h4>     
    <ul>
      <li><a href="<s:url action='myJasperTest'/>">Click</a></li>   
    </ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

**Exception shown in the browser**

**type**  `Exception report`

**message**

**description**  `The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from  fulfilling this request.`

**exception**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:515)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:419)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:89)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:601)
    org.apache.struts2.views.jasperreports.JasperReportsResult.doExecute(JasperReportsResult.java:240)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:178)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:348)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:253)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:150)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:48)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:167)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:105)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:83)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:207)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:74)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:127)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:107)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:206)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:115)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:143)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:121)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:170)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:123)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:50)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:504)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:419)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.22 logs.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your

```
<param name="dataSource">beanCollection</param>
```

**can't** be right.

You should return an `ArrayList` of `Person`s, but you are declaring and instantiating it without specifying the `type` and... you are adding a `String` to it, not a `Person` !!

```
public static ArrayList<Person> getBeanCollection() {
    ArrayList as=new ArrayList();
            as.add("val"); // <- what ?!
    return as;
}
```

change it to:

```
public static ArrayList<Person> getBeanCollection() {        
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("val"); //setName, or set something...

    ArrayList<Person> as=new ArrayList()<Person>;
    as.add(person);
    return as;
}
```

Comment: Now i'm getting Another Exception as javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStyle to field net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph.paragraphContainer of type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParagraphContainer in instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph
 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:515)
 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:419)

root cau

Answer (score 0):

Root cause of the exception says:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:89)
```

Explore the [JRFiller](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports/4.0.1/jasperreports-4.0.1-javadoc.jar!/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/fill/JRFiller.html) 4.0.1 API. It expects parameter Map.

The only thing that can cause a `NullPointerException` in this line is the case when filler is null. The parameters are not checked for null at this point.

So, check your datasource   `<param name="dataSource">beanCollection</param>`

On a side note, You have not mentioned which JasperReports version you are using. Always mention API version. Its a good practice.

Comment: actually my Jasper does'nt need any external parameters....................i does'nt need the arraylist returned from beanCollection......so what will i do then